# Random Samples of XX rows per Column Value

Tags: sql

I'm using T-SQL and require some sample output of random rows.
Typically I would write some SQL as per below

```
Select top 10 *
from SampleTable as ST
Order by NewID()
```

However this time I want say 100 rows but them split equally by another column value for instance Column 'Type'.
100 Rows with a sample of 25 rows for TypeA , 25 rows for Type B, 25 rows for Type C and lastly 25 rows for Type D scenerio.

My 'Type' values are saved to a temp table

```
Select top 10 *
from SampleTable as ST
Inner Join #Types as TY 
  on TY.Type = ST.Type
Order by NewID()
```

I've seen NTILE but not sure if applicable for my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` in conjunction with `NEWID()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ST.Type ORDER BY NEWID()) rn
    FROM SampleTable AS ST
    INNER JOIN #TypesAS TY ON TY.Type = ST.Type
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 25;
```

The above solution will return 25 records from each type (or however many fewer might be available), randomly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I didn't provide all the information, the base table is millions but performance is fine for my purpose. I should have tested before posting question, as half ruled out do ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY due to performance.